# How can I track NIC activity in C#? Specifically ingress/egress by port

Tags: c#, winapi, networking, bandwidth

I need to track the amount of data that each application is sending and recieving by port, in C#.

What is the correct API or .NET object to use?

Answer (score 0):

The data exposed by Performance Monitor (`perfmon`) is readily available to applications through HKEY_PERFORMANCE_DATA.  However, it doesn't contain the level of detail you require.

Resource Monitor (`resmon`) does display network activity by process (though not by port) and it uses Event Tracing for Windows (ETW).  To reproduce `resmon` data in your app you'd need to capture events from ETW and sum up the totals yourself.  I don't know if the trace data contains enough information to break the totals down by port number, but I'd be surprised if it didn't.  ETW data is usually very detailed.  However, I don't believe there's any support for consuming ETW data in .Net.  ETW can produce events at a *very* high rate, so it would probably be better to write a native DLL to consume and aggregate the data.

A simpler option is to find an existing tool.  Here's a [starting point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd569137%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).